# Axis LabelStyle not working in FSharpChart?

Tags: f#, fsharpchart, f#-charting

I can't work out how to change the font on the Axes in [FSharpChart.WithArea](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/FSharpChart-b59073f5).

This is the shortest example I could come up with that displays the problem (on my machine, at least).

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll"
#r "MSDN.FSharp.Charting.dll"
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
open MSDN.FSharp.Charting
open System.Drawing

let font = new Font("Wingdings", 10.0F)

FSharpChart.FastLine([(0.,1.);(10., 10.)])
|> FSharpChart.WithArea.AxisX(LabelStyle = new LabelStyle(Font = font))
|> FSharpChart.WithCreate
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the library. If you want to fix it yourself, download the source code and find a line that defines `typesToClone`. It should look something like this:

```
let typesToClone = 
    [ typeof<LabelStyle>; typeof<Axis>; typeof<Grid>; typeof<TickMark>
      typeof<ElementPosition>; typeof<AxisScaleView>; typeof<AxisScrollBar>; ]
```

This defines a list of types whose properties are copied when creating a chart. The problem is that the name `LabelStyle` refers to a type in the F# Charting Library's source code rather than to the .NET chart controls type `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelStyle`. It can be fixed by using the full type name:

```
let typesToClone = 
    [ typeof<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelStyle>; 
      typeof<Axis>; typeof<Grid>; typeof<TickMark>
      typeof<ElementPosition>; typeof<AxisScaleView>; typeof<AxisScrollBar>; ]
```

I'll send this information to the current maintainers of the library to make sure the next version includes a fix for this. Thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but with that, my snippet above complains that `System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type`.